# R: constructing variable name for assignment

Tags: r

I have constructed 3 global vectors:

```
assign("sec1",  rep(NA_real_, 800), envir = .GlobalEnv)
assign("sec2",  rep(NA_real_, 800), envir = .GlobalEnv)
assign("sec3",  rep(NA_real_, 800), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

In a function F, I am trying to populate them:

```
v <- parse.message()
n <- lookup.security()
m <- lookup.time.bucket()

assign(paste0("sec", n , "[", m, "]"), v, envir = .GlobalEnv)  # line 220
```

The above is not populating sec1, sec2, and sec3 vectors. Instead it is creating new global variables sec1[314], sec2[400] etc.

Is there anyway to do what I am trying to do in line 220 of my code?

I can not alter the parameter list of function F because the API in question doesn't allow for this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval(parse(text =` will do what you need, but it is generally not a good idea to use text in order to do data manipulation / assignments. There is usually a better way of doing this.

Having said that:

```
n <- 1
m <- 314
v <- 5
sec1 <- rep(NA, 800)
eval(parse(text = paste0("sec", n , "[", m, "]" , '<-', v)))
```

Output:

```
> summary(sec1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
      5       5       5       5       5       5     799
```